# Area of circle and parabola

Tags: definite-integrals, surface-integrals

I shall determine the surface area of the intersection of a circle with Radius $R= 1 $ and the set of points above the parabola $f(x) = 2x^2$. Only the positive $x,y$-plane is of interest.

My approach is to parameterize it with polar coordinates as $x=R\cos(\phi)$ and $y=R\sin(\phi)$, thus  $\vec \gamma(\phi) =  \begin{pmatrix}
        R \cos(\phi) \\
        R \sin(\phi) \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

Now I struggle with setting bounds of the integral, something like $0 \le R \le 1 $ and $? \le \phi \le ?.$

I have determined the point of intersection as $x=0.62481$, thus $\phi = 51.332°$ or $\phi = 0.896$ in rad. How do I continue?

Comment: Is the circle centred at origin?

Comment: What is the center of the circle?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add that. Yes, the circle is centered in the origin.

Comment: jumping in three dimension as you do for $\stackrel{\to}\gamma(\phi)$ is unnecessary and adds confusion

Comment: I used three dimensions because you have to determine $\frac{\partial \vec \gamma}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial \vec \gamma}{\partial y}$ which is only defined in three dimensions

Answer (score 1):

I will assume the circle is centered at the origin since you did not state.

We will have the equation of the circle: $x^2+y^2=1$

For the parabola, we have $y=2x^2$

To get the points of intersection, we just have to set y=$2x^2$ in the equation of the parabola.

$x^2+4x^4=1$

Solving the equation, we get $x=0.68,-0.68$ as you said.

You should note that $y=2x^2$ is above the x-axis and thus we can take only the upper semicircle, and thus $y=\sqrt{(1-x^2)}$

Now, to continue, all we have to do is compute the integral $\int_{0}^{0.68} (\sqrt{(1-x^2)}-2x^2\,dx$

We set $x=\sin(\theta)$ so $dx=\cos(\theta)\,d\theta$ When $x=0,\theta=0$ and $x=0.68,\theta=0.74$ so the limits of integration are set.

We now calculate the indefinite integral:

\begin{align}
& \int \sqrt{1-x^2}-2x^2\,dx=\int (\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta} -2\sin^2(\theta))\cos(\theta) \, d\theta \\[8pt]
= {} & \int \cos^2(\theta) \,d\theta-2\int \sin^2 \theta \cos(\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2} \int 1+\cos(2\theta)\,d\theta \\[6pt]
& {} -2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\int \cos(\theta)-\cos(3\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\theta + \frac{1}{4} \sin(2\theta)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta)+\frac{1}{6}\sin(3\theta)
\end{align}

Now, putting the values at the limit of integration, we get:
Area=0.41

Comment: Since we are only interested in the quadrant where x and y are positive, shouldn't the limit be from 0 to 0.68 ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't read that we're interested in the x-y positive part of the plane. It was a mistake of hurry. Let me correct my answer.

Comment: I did it myself and get $0.37545$

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28sqrt%281-x^2%29-2x^2%29+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D0.62)

It's probably a difference in estimation, or you forgot to calculate something.

Answer (score 0):

here is way to find the area without polar coordinates. the parabola $y = 2x^2$ and the unit circle cut at $(\pm \sqrt{b/2}, b)$ where $b = {\sqrt{17} - 1  \over 4}$ is the positive solutions of the quadratic equation $y^2 + {y \over 2} = 1$

the area is $$2\int_0^b \sqrt{y \over 2} \ dy + \arccos b - b\sqrt{1 - b^2}={2\sqrt 2 \over 3} b^{3/2} +\arccos b - b\sqrt{1 - b^2}$$